# My boot volume is full, what should I do now?

Tags: boot, kernel

I keep on getting an urgent error message telling me my BOOT volume is full!
How can I safely clean this up? Please be aware, I am a newbie in Linux.

This is the result of `uname -a`:

```
Linux ESPRIMO-E3500 3.13.0-53-generic #89-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 20 10:34:28 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

I installed the *Synaptic package manager* and looked at the status window "Auto Removable":
There are things like `System.map-3.13.0-46-generic`

**But which of them (if any) can I remove?**
Thanks in advance for your help!

## P.S. How can I best provide the right info for anyone to advise me as I may not yet post images?

As requested:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image-
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-30-generic                         3.13.0-30.55                                        i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic                         3.13.0-46.79                                        i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-48-generic                         3.13.0-48.80                                        i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-49-generic                         3.13.0-49.83                                        i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic                         3.13.0-51.84                                        i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic                         3.13.0-52.86                                        i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-53-generic                         3.13.0-53.89                                        i386         Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-30-generic                   3.13.0-30.55                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-46-generic                   3.13.0-46.79                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-48-generic                   3.13.0-48.80                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-49-generic                   3.13.0-49.83                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-51-generic                   3.13.0-51.84                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic                   3.13.0-52.86                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iF  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-53-generic                   3.13.0-53.89                                        i386         Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic                                   3.13.0.53.60                                        i386         Generic Linux kernel image
```

So when I run "sudo apt-get autoremove" the response is now:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

By the way I did manually delete several older linux-image files in /boot.

The output now for "*apt-get update* and ***apt-get dist-upgrade*** "

Fetched 1166 kB in 20s (56,0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Just to be clear on the current situation:

Device: /dev/sda1 
Size:  255 MB — 39 MB free (84,6% full)

Device: /dev/zorin-os-vg/swap_1
Contents:  Swap (version 2) — Active
Size: 1,6 GB (1602224128 bytes)

uname -r :  sudo uname -r
3.13.0-62-generic

dpkg -l | grep linux-image-

rc  linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic                         3.13.0-57.95
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic                         3.13.0-58.97
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic                         3.13.0-59.98
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic                         3.13.0-61.100 
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic                         3.13.0-62.102
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic                   3.13.0-57.95
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-58-generic                   3.13.0-58.97 
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic                   3.13.0-59.98
rc  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic                   3.13.0-61.100
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic                   3.13.0-62.102
ii  linux-image-generic                                   3.13.0.62.69

Strangely (or not perhaps) I am still getting the message that my /Boot is full.

So to check the status I used: df -Th | sort
Result:

/dev/mapper/zorin--os--vg-root ext4      145G  8,9G  129G   7% /
/dev/sda1                      ext2      236M  235M     0 100% /boot
/dev/sdb                       vfat      967M  233M  735M  25% /media/home/SAN
Filesystem                     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none                           tmpfs     100M   24K  100M   1% /run/user
none                           tmpfs     4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                           tmpfs     5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                           tmpfs     750M   80K  750M   1% /run/shm
tmpfs                          tmpfs     150M  1,4M  149M   1% /run
udev                           devtmpfs  737M  4,0K  737M   1% /dev

I then searched again for the latest Keernel file:

uname -r
3.13.0-63-generic

Running: ls /usr/src | grep linux-headers
seems to show that I have cleaned out all unrequired kernels:

linux-headers-3.13.0-62
linux-headers-3.13.0-62-generic
linux-headers-3.13.0-63
linux-headers-3.13.0-63-generic

Strangely if I run: dpkg -l | grep linux-image

I still see all listings such as:

rc  linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic   3.13.0-57.95
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-58-generic   3.13.0-58.97 
rc  linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic   3.13.0-59.98

This despite running all kinds of purge commands.

So someone suggested running: sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
to clear out everything except the last kernel.

Result:

gzip: stdout: **No space left on device**
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

So it would seem that there are still to many files in my /boot
When I check using **ls -alhR /boot**

I see that several old Kernel files are still there:

-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M jul 25 01:11 abi-3.13.0-59-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1,2M jul 29 14:40 abi-3.13.0-61-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 166K jul 25 01:11 config-3.13.0-59-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 166K jul 29 14:40 config-3.13.0-61-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  27M jul 28 02:40 initrd.img-3.13.0-59-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  27M aug  6 03:09 initrd.img-3.13.0-61-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 2,6M jul 25 01:11 System.map-3.13.0-59-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 2,6M jul 29 14:40 System.map-3.13.0-61-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 5,6M jul 25 01:11 vmlinuz-3.13.0-59-generic
-rw-------  1 root root 5,6M jul 29 14:40 vmlinuz-3.13.0-61-generic

I just ran: **sudo apt-get update** and **sudo apt-get autoremove**

result:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic (3.13.0-63.103) ...
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.13.0-63-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 3.13.0-63-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-63-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic
 linux-image-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Kept on looking for a solution and fouond this command "script"

**dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/(.*)-([^0-9]+)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* ([^ ]*).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge**

When running this command it indicates:
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-62* linux-headers-3.13.0-62-generic*
  linux-image-3.13.0-62-generic* linux-image-extra-3.13.0-62-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 223 MB disk space will be freed.

And it does as those files are nowhere to be found any more. But it also says:

Generating grub configuration file ...
Found theme: /boot/grub/themes/Zorin/theme.txt
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-63-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-63-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-61-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-61-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-59-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-59-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done

and here I see the old 3.13.0-59-generic and 3.13.0-61-generic again which are obviously still taking up unnecessary space.

Two questions there for remain....

ONE - How can I adapt 
"**dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/(.*)-([^0-9]+)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* ([^ ]*).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge**"

So it also deletes these old kernel files?

TWO - It would seem that best practise is to have at least the two most recent kernels installed on the computer and I just wiped one of those, can I still reinstall "3.13.0-62-generic" and how?

Thanks for your help as always.

---

thanks to all for helping me.

Not quite sure whether I have decided on the best method, but I now tend just use:

sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get autoremove

every now and then.

Still, I need to find a way to increase my boot partition size because I somehow doubt whether the above mentioned method will be enough in the future.

Best Regards

Comment: Is your /boot at a separate partition?

Comment: can you add the result of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image-` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a seperate /boot partion. This happens over time as you upgrade your kernel. In my experience, if you get an error telling you that you have no space left while running a `dist-upgrade` you can run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then the system will remove the old kernel and install the new one. If you want to remove the kernels you are not using, you can easily use synaptic by searching for `linux-headers` and `linux-image`. Synaptic will show you all of the kernels you have, and you can right click on each one and click `mark for removal`. Just make sure you don't remove *all* of them. Remove all but the latest (it's good to leave one in case something breaks so you can fall back).

Comment: Autoremove won't install any "new" kernel. Linux-headers are not kernels.

Comment: Actaully I may be mistaken. I believe you have to run `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` again after running autoremove. That seemed to  solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Begin to execute this command to check which version you are running:

`uname -r`

Then check linux headers and image currently installed :

```
dpkg -l | grep -Ei "linux-headers|linux-image"
```

Finally purge old version (here 3.13.0-30):

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-headers-3.13.0-30 linux-headers-3.13.0-30-generic linux-image-3.13.0-30-generic linux-image-extra-3.13.0-30-generic --purge
```

**NOTE :** Be carefull, do not purge the current version you are running.
Also, try to keep one or two older version just in case.